# How to solve $a_1 \sin (x+y) + a_2 \sin (x-y)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking for methods on how to solve;

$$a_1 \sin (x+y) + a_2 \sin (x-y)=0$$

where

1) $a_1, a_2$ are constants

2)  $a_1, a_2$ are functions of $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 2):

Taking $a_1=0$ you have clearly an infinity of straight lines $x-y=k\pi$ with slope $1$ and so is for $a_2=0$ with slope $-1$. Analogously you have for $a_1a_2\ne 0$ infinitely many parallel curves. Puting $c=\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ you have squares for $c=\pm1$ and sinusoidal curves for other values of $c$ (*see the figures below*). All this is because of
$$c(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)+\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y=0\\(c+1)\sin x\cos y+(c-1)\cos x \sin y=0\Rightarrow\begin{cases}\tan x=(c-1)t\\\tan y=(c+1)t\end{cases}$$ where $t\in \Bbb R$. In other words
$$\begin{cases}x=\arctan (c-1)t\\y=\arctan(c+1)t\end{cases}$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expand out the sines and collect terms:

$$ (a_1 + a_2) \sin(x) \cos(y) + (a_1 - a_2) \cos(x) \sin(y) = 0 $$
Thus, assuming $\cos(x) \ne 0$, 
$$(a_1 + a_2) \tan(x) = (a_2 - a_1) \tan(y)$$